# How do you display headers and footers in an embedded Google Doc <iframe>?

Tags: html, css, iframe, google-docs

I am embedding a Google Doc in a HTML . My Google Doc has a footer that contains the page number and an image. I would like for the doc to display the footer on my web page. Below is the current code:

```
<div class="scroll-wrapper">
 <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vR59LAO6EgV98_OVPaMO_WcI3Ds7Nemf0WzFO7xgYXoEXlnqDWncLsyCwvpQNUrBhQUUmmhp_TqKIRn/pub?embedded=true"></iframe></div>
```

and the css class:

```
.scroll-wrapper {
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
overflow-y: scroll;
position: 0; 
right: 0; 
bottom: 0; 
left: 0;
top: 0;
display: block;
text-align:center;
}

.scroll-wrapper iframe {
height: 750px;
width: 56.25%;
}
```

If this can't be accomplished using my current code, what are some alternate ways of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have never worked with Google docs and also I couldn't find "Page number" in your Google docs file.

Assuming you can edit the Google docs footer, assign a id to your footer div inside your Google document.

Example:

```
<div class="your-footer" id="target-footer">
    ....
</div>
```

Then just use a simple  and use the jQuery "load" function to load the whole page and pluck out just the section you want:
Then create an empty div in your page where you are showing the iframe.

```
<div id="target-div"> </div>
```

Finally the jQuery:

```
$('#target-div').load('https://docs.google.com/document/d/e/2PACX-1vR59LAO6EgV98_OVPaMO_WcI3Ds7Nemf0WzFO7xgYXoEXlnqDWncLsyCwvpQNUrBhQUUmmhp_TqKIRn/pub?embedded=true #target-footer');
```

Hope this provides you with some help.